# Why do we need middleware in FASTapi?

Tags: api, middleware

[From official documentation:](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/)

**A "middleware" is a function that works with every request before it is processed by any specific path operation. And also with every response before returning it.**

But I would like to ask what is the point of a middleware in FASTapi? What problems does it solve? Can you please provide me a simple explanation?

For an example I have created a test API, with database and all works pretty fine. I don't see a need to implement a middleware at all, or at least I don't see a point of it.

Comment: security, logging, error handling etc etc

Comment: It's basically a plug-in mechanism - the framework provides you with a thing that works, but allows you to customize it by "plugging in" extra stuff - the various middleware (can come from a 3rd-party library, or can be written by you, or a combination of both).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *have* to use middlewares – but it's a popular mechanism in web frameworks to allow you to do something for every request.

For example, you might apply a middleware to log every incoming request. This is easier than adding the logging to every route.

Or you might apply a middleware to certain routes to ensure that the client is properly authorized. This is safer than adding the authorization check to every route, since you can't forget the check when adding a new route.

Sometimes you will use a third party library to provide such functionality – and that library will likely be implemented in terms of a middleware. Middlewares provide an extension point where code can hook into the request lifecycle.

The idea of middlewares can also be seen as an instance of the object-oriented design patterns *chain of responsibility* and/or *decorator*.

Comment: +1 one of the things I've done specifically with FastAPI middlewares is to update the 'state' variable of the request with a UUID and ensuring it is used in logging and returned with the response headers.  It's very useful for troubleshooting.